# Get link by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want the link by class name.

```
 <a class="someclass" href="http://demo.theme.com/theme1">Demo</a>
```

is there any way to get that link with javascript?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: i'm spanish :P i edited the question i hope u can understand now

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking for. You want to get the `href` attribute of a clicked link?

Comment: i want that href='http://demo.theme.com/theme1' by the class with javascript to put on other button that link,,, now?

Comment: And why can't you do it manually?

Comment: because i did that on 30 posts it means if i want to change that i will have to edit 30 posts so thats why i'm trying to do with javascript

Comment: You would still need to edit those 30 posts if you wanted to use Javascript to replace the `href` attributes for specific links. You would need to assign a unique class to each link you wanted to replace, otherwise every single link on your website would be replaced with that `href`. If you're using some sort of CMS, like Wordpress, your best bet would be to do a search/replace in the database to swap out the links.

Comment: i don't want to replace the href i want that href to use on other class.

Comment: Ya, you want to use that href to replace the href of other links. Javascript is not the way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option will be

```
document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0].getAttribute('href')
```

Comment: Just an FYI this will only work for IE9+ (lets hope you are not working with anything less than 9!) http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname

Comment: Internet explorer is evil prior to version 35 ;-)

Comment: i want that link on other link for example: <a href="#">Demo</a> i want that 'someclass' link on that '#'

Comment: @michael, supporting IE8 is the bane of my life at the moment

Comment: I feel with you... @UsainBloot

Comment: @user2397942, selecting a dom element by href is not really the best way to go about it. Is there a way you could perhaps change your approach to use class or id instead? Sometimes I find that the approach to the problem is what I need to change.

Comment: @UsainBloot i can't change now not even name of class because it has been working on 30 posts if i will change so i will have to edit every post

Comment: @user2397942 hmm that is trickier, its pretty straight forward with jQuery. I will have a think how to do it with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: is there any way to chat with u? bcz i don't have enough points so i can't chat here i will show u my site and what i want to do